# Awk act as a substitution

Tags: awk, substitution

I have a list of arrays with different information on which I am doing an awk.

```
number  location  length  value

 1        2         40     0.96
---       5         45     0.97
 4        5         47     0.96
---       5         35     0.95
 2        5         60     0.95
---       3         55     0.96


awk '{if ($2=5 && $3 >= 40 && $3<=50 && $6>=0.96) print $0}' Infile.txt
```

It does give me the correct row `---       5         45     0.97` and `4        5         47     0.96`. 
However, if I want to add another condition, such as `$1= ---`, to only have the first output `--- 5 45 0.97`

```
 awk '{if ($2=5 && $3 >= 40 && $3<=50 && $6>=0.96 && $1="\-\-\-") print $0}' Infile.txt >List_position.txt
```

it acts as a substitution, returning the previous output as `1  5 45 0.97` and `1 5 47 0.96`. 
I tried with `$1=---`, `$1='\-\-\-'` and they both didn't work. If I try with `$1="---"`, it substitutes $1 to `---`.

I am new with awk and I really don't understand why it does a substitution. If `" "` is a substitution in awk, how can I put a condition on `---`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've done an assignment `=` instead of comparison `==` (and the result of the assignment evaluates to true because it is neither 0 nor an empty string).

```
awk '{if ($2==5 && $3 >= 40 && $3<=50 && $6>=0.96 && $1=="---") print }' Infile.txt >List_position.txt
```

You also have the '`=` vs `==`' problem with the `$2=5` assignment in the condition, but you didn't notice it because you were expecting to see 5 there (and thanks to [JS웃](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970195/js) for pointing that out).

You also don't need the backslashes.

Comment: Thanks! So `=` instead of `==` changes $1 for what comes after?

Comment: In fact, `$2=5` is well written in my script as `$2==5`. I should have seen the difference

Comment: Yes; in C and derivative languages such as `awk`, C++, Java and Perl (to name but a few), you can do assignments in expressions, and the value assigned is the result of the assignment and can be used in another assignment (`a = b = 23`) or in a comparison (being careful with precedences).